# Uniswap V3 contract: how to detect source and destination coin

Tags: uniswapv3, swaps

I am working to an information parser  and stuck with Uniswap V3 smart contract behaviour.

first case: ***Swap 2,093,700 WPLS For 0.1129 ETH***
[https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcb828a8f1b9e0066b18b1dd23057d1bb7c7a42c51a6ac2d1e382e8f394c4b803](https://stackoverflow.com)

amount1 is always for ETH and amount0 is  WPLS. you can identify the direction: from WPLS (amount1 positive value) to ETH (amount1 negative)

and that situation is identical for almost all contracts with signature - **0xc42079f94a6350d7e6235f29174924f928cc2ac818eb64fed8004e115fbcca67**

But if you take the second case:
[https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcd348172fbb5180da283055c644c17bf77706328e611994935be6d7b183cef90](https://stackoverflow.com)

you will find that COCO is stored in amount1 (positive) and ETH is in amount0 (negative)
but how they did found that transfers from from COCO to ETH ?

That is written in Transaction Action:
***Swap 27,567.36 COCO For 1.4552 ETH***